# XORing list of binary values

Tags: python, binary

I would like to make a simple function which encodes a string.
The idea is as follows:

1. Change a string to a list of corresponding binary values.
2. Change a chosen number to a corresponding binary value.
3. XOR with each other.
4. Change back to a string.

So this is my code:

```
def encode (text, key):
textbit=[]
encoded=[]
keybit=bin(key)
for a in text:
    textbit.append(bin(ord(a)))
for x in xrange (0, len(textbit)):
    encoded.append(textbit[x])^(keybit) 
return 0

word='abcdef'
encode(word, 243)
```

While I'm trying to run it, an error is returned:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'NoneType' and 'str'.

Could you tell me how to fix that?

Comment: Please remove that `xrange` and iterate over `textbit` directly. And for your problem, try removing the `bin` that gives a string of the number.

Comment: You can do this as a one-liner: `''.join([chr(ord(i) ^ key) for i in text])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because of the parenthesis: you want to add the result of the xor but instead you try to xor what `encoded.append(...)` returns.

But they are many other problems, I have fixed some of them but not all (you probably want to add a return and convert back to a string too):

```
def encode(text, key):
    textbit = []
    encoded = []
    for a in text:
        textbit.append(ord(a))
    for x in textbit:
        encoded.append(x ^ key)

word = 'abcdef'
encode(word, 243)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in your code (apart from other stylistic considerations):

First of all you misplaced the parenthesis when trying to append the result of your XOR expression: you wrote `encoded.append(textbit[x])^(keybit)` instead of `encoded.append(textbit[x]^keybit)`. The misplaced parenthesis caused Python to try to perform a XOR between the result of `append` (which is always `None`) and `keybit`, which is a string, as reported by the error message.

However, even changing your code from `encoded.append(textbit[x])^(keybit)` to `encoded.append(textbit[x]^keybit)` will cause Python to report an error. In fact the new code will try to perform a XOR between the two strings `textbit[x]` and `keybit`, built by function `bin` (which returns a string - not a number - containing the binary representation of an integer number), but the XOR operator accepts just integers.

However this second problem has a simple solution: you have to keep in mind that all integer numbers are stored internally in a computer as binary numbers. Therefore there is no need to convert them into another format (e.g. using `bin`), before using them with binary operators.

Taking into account of these considerations (and making the `encode` function returns the encoded string, instead of a useless `0`), your function becomes:

```
def encode(text, key):
    textbit = []
    encoded = []
    for a in text:
        textbit.append(ord(a))
    for x in textbit:
        encoded.append(chr(x^key)) 
    return ''.join(encoded)
```

Taking advantage of [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), you can make some simplifications:

```
def encode(text, key):
    textbit = [ord(a) for a in text]
    encoded = [chr(x^key) for x in textbit]
    return ''.join(encoded)
```

Getting rid of the simple temporary step to compute `textbit`, the function can be written:

```
def encode(text, key):
    encoded = [chr(ord(a)^key) for a in text]
    return ''.join(encoded)
```

This can be reduced to a single line function as:

```
def encode(text, key):
    return ''.join([chr(ord(a)^key) for a in text])
```

or, using [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), as:

```
def encode(text, key):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(a)^key) for a in text)
```

which is the one-liner suggested by Klaus D.